# Specify only a subset of Type Arguments when calling a Generic Method? (Java)

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have the following method declaration:

```java
public static <E, RetType> RetType doSomething(
            E instance,
            String methodName,
            Object... params
    ) {...}
```

One of the argument types may not always be correctly inferred by the compiler.

Is there a way to specify only one (or a subset) of the type arguments when calling the method?

I could call this method either specifying all the type arguments:

```java
DoSomethingClass.<InstanceType, ReturnType>doSomething(...);
```

Or without type arguments:

```java
DoSomethingClass.doSomething(...);
```

Yet I would like to achieve something like

```java
<RetType = SpecificType>doSomething(...);
```

Comment: You can't in Java you either specify all or none. It's a language limitation.

Comment: @RaduSebastianLAZIN I see, thank you. If you could write this as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in Java. You either specify all or none. It's a language limitation.

(as of Java 21, maybe some day)